# Error: Image.clipToBoundsAndScale, argument 'input': Invalid type. Expected type: Image<unknown bands>. Actual type: ImageCollection. (Error code: 3)

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a problem with my script, I'm trying to download a landsat image, and I'm having some problems with the error:

```
function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

var image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
                  .filterDate('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31')
                  .filterBounds(bogor)
                  .map(maskL8sr);

var visParams = {
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4,
};
Map.centerObject(bogor, 10);
Map.addLayer(image.median(), visParams);

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: image,
  description: 'bogor2016',
  scale: 10,
  region: bogor
});
```

I've checked my script in detail and can't find that I'm doing anything wrong on the calculation part, but I haven't found any related references to help solve my problem.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=Invalid+type.+Expected+type%3A+Image+Actual+type%3A+ImageCollection.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to download an imageCollection, so a quick solution is to change the location of the function `.median()` to create a single image:

```
var image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
                  .filterDate('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31')
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
                  .map(maskL8sr)
                  .median();
```

Here is the code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/69f3f744fcc08f9269afc6b979f79a27